# How to create two dependent html dropdown list using php arrays and/or sql

Tags: php, html, list, multidimensional-array

So I need to create two dropdown lists where second list is dependent on the first one. For example:

In first list I may have options like this:

- A
- B
- C
- D

When users selects A, then he will get to chose additional options in second dropdown based on the first dropdown. So In case user chose A in first list, options in second list may be:

- A-1
- A-2
- A-3

How can I do this in php and html ? Do I have to use multidimensional arrays ? Maybe database ? How would I detect what user has selected in first list and offer him proper options in second ?

Comment: Depending on how extensive, you would probably want to use a combination of `AJAX` and `PHP`, but you could do it all with just php.

Comment: That's a broad question, @shone.  Your solution is going to involve JavaScript, probably AJAX, might involve the database if the content of the lists is derived from the database. It sounds like it probably is, since the second list is dependent on the filter condition selected in the first. Etc.

Comment: What about multidimensional arrays like this: $data = ['A'=> ['A-1', 'A-2']]; Is it posbile to output first array (A, B, C) in one dropdown and second array (A-1, A-2, B-1, B-2) in other ? Somehow... ? Edit: but when user selects A in first to get only A-1, A-2... in second

Answer (score 1):

With HTML and PHP only you could do this with a multidimensional array like this:

```
<?php
$list = array(
    "A" => array("A-1", "A-2", "A-3"),
    "B" => array("B-1", "B-2"),
    "C" => array("C-1"),
    "D" => array("D-1", "D-2", "D-3", "D-4"),
);
?>

<form>
    <select name="first_input">
        <?php foreach ($list as $first => $second) { ?>
            <option><?php print ($first); ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php if (isset($_GET["first_input"])) { ?>

    <form>
        <select name="second_input">
            <?php foreach ($list[$_GET["first_input"]] as $second) { ?>
                <option><?php print ($second); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </form>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did one the other day using a multidimensional array.

```
var options = {
    "Option 1" : [ "1A","1B","1C" ],
    "Option 2" : [ "2A","2B","2C" ],
    "Option 3" : [ "3A","3B","3C" ]
}
```

Then something like:

#### jQuery:

```
$.each(options,function(a,b){
    $('#select1').append('<option>'+a+'</option>');
});

$('#select1').change(function(){
    var sel1 = $(this).val();
    $.each(option[$sel1],function(a,b) {
        $('#select2').append('<option>'+b+'</option>');
    });
});
```

(This is the concept... this actual syntax may or may not be error-ridden.)

Comment: It's the right idea yes, doesn't address how to get the options from PHP, `.append` may not work depending on the `<select>` structure (default `<option value=''></option>` present?), etc etc, but the right idea.